# Database script issues with linked server

Tags: sql-server, database, production-environment, linked-server

I have a problem with our database scripts. We have three environments: DEV, QA and UAT. We have two databases: `DB1` and `DB2`. On DEV/QA those two databases are on different physical servers hence we have a linked server to `DB2` in `DB1`. However on UAT it is a single server with both databases.

Our issue is that the scripts we write involve referring the `DB2` using the `DB2` linked server, which fails in UAT. The process we adopt is to use manual ways to deploy to UAT, which is not efficient.

Can someone suggest what can be done to better this?

Comment: Are you trying to promote your scripts from dev/qa to UAT?

Comment: In UAT define a pair of linked servers, just as in DEV/QA, that point back to itself with the names used in DEV/QA. ***However***, in this day and age of cheap virtual machines, WHY are you running your DEV and QA environments differently from your UAT environment? You have probably wasted more labour dollars already than a server license would cost.

Comment: I would normally have all the links in UAT and pull data from the dev/qa environments. In UAT you will have to versions of sps each referring to dev/qa, same code different sources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a linked server in your UAT environment's database referencing itself, with the same name as the linked server in your DEV/QA environment.

Suppose the server name of the UAT's database is `MYUATSRVNAME` (use the output of `SELECT @@SERVERNAME`). You can create a self-referencing linked server with the same name as the linked server name used in your DEV/QA's `DB1`. Suppose that name is `UVWXYZ`, on your UAT database execute

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @server='UVWXYZ',@srvproduct='',@provider='SQLNCLI',@datasrc='MYUATSRVNAME';
```

That way you can use the same scripts referencing the same linked server name. Eg this query should then work in `DB1` on both DEV/QA and UAT:

```
SELECT * FROM [UVWXYZ].[DB2].[your_schema].[your_table];
```

Comment: I have made this an answer because it answers my questions. However, the problem of having a self referencing linked server is that it is a "Loopback Linked Server" actually reduces performances and also cannot be executed on distributed transactions. 

Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: @Immortal You're welcome. Is performance a big issue in your UAT environment? You raise good points regarding performance and distributed transactions, but other than recreating the setup on UAT the same as DEV/QA I see no way to keep your SQL scripts the same.

Comment: yes you are right, that is why it is a struggling point for me now :( unfortunately.